# Global sidebar with Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I want to create a "sidebar" to show in all pages, example:

Show recent posts in all views, included when is another controller's view.

Comment: did you create any layout!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Inside the AppController, in beforeFilter method.

```
$myModel = TableRegistry::get('nameOfModel');
$query = $myModel->find();
$this->set('query', $query);
```

And then create an element with this var.